# Can anyone prove this result?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am reading a set of lecture notes on the quantum order-finding algorithm, and they take this result to be true:

$\displaystyle\sum_{t=0}^{r-1} \ e^{\frac{-2 \pi i k t}{r}} = r\delta_{k,0}$

I cannot seem to prove that this result is true myself, and I was wondering if anyone had any thoughts?

Comment: What is $\delta_{k,0}$?

Comment: I assume the Kronecker delta

Comment: I thought that maybe expanding it to a sum of sines and cosines would be an option, but that didn't seem to work

Comment: Gauß can. Look up "Gauss sums". (Although this is indeed an easy case of geometric series.) Your summands are roots of unity.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the standard formula for geometric sums, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series